# Is this possible with regular Expressions in Dreamweaver?

Tags: html, css, regex, dreamweaver

I'm working on a CSS file in Dreamweaver. There are 100's of lines like this:

`.ab_{background-image:url(../path/path/path/path/xxxxx.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;}`

**ab_** must stay the same
**xxxxx** is different. Example, xxx01, xxx02, etc.
**ab_xxxxx** is what I want to append.

I want to get `xxxxx` value and put it near the beginning, after the ab_ like this:

`.ab_xxxxxx{background-image:url(../path01/path02/path03/path04/xxxxx.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;}`

so another one would be

`.ab_xxxx45{background-image:url(../path01/path02/path03/path04/xxx45.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;}`

I'm not sure if this possible, I know regular expressions can be tricky, but if this is possible could someone point in me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find: `\.ab_(.+/([^/]+)\.jpg)`

Replace: `.ab_$2$1`

Explanation:

`.ab_` matches the literal text ".ab_".

`(.+/([^/]+)\.jpg)` matches up to ".jpg" and stores the result in `$1`.

`/([^/]+)` matches a forward slash then captures anything that is not a forward slash up to ".jpg" and stores it in `$2`.

Comment: will this work for multiple instance, say , xxx01, xxx02, up to 500 hundred?

Comment: this almost works, but the result is counting the results, adding a '01', '02' '03' at the end.

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't the point to copy the "01", "02", "03"? Or do you want to copy only the part before the number?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in my question. The XXXXX is a random mix of numbers and letters. I need to copy from '/' to '.jpeg'. Basically, the filename is what I'm trying to name as the new class.

Comment: .ab_xxxxxx{background-image:url(../path01/path02/path03/path04/xxxxx.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;} would have to be  

.**ab_babab**{background-image:url(../path01/path02/path03/path04/**babab**.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;}

Comment: The regex in my answer will replace `.ab_{background-image:url(../path/xxxxxx.jpg);` with `.ab_xxxxxx{background-image:url(../path/xxxxxx.jpg);`. Is that not what you need?

Comment: it is adding a '01', '02', etc at the end of each. the first is becoming xxxxx01, the second is xxxxx02, the third xxxxx03

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about dreamweaver regex, but try this in notepad++

search : `^\.ab_(.*)\/(.*).jpg(.*)$`
replace with : `.ab_\2\1/\2.jpg\3`

It's not the most accurate regex, but it seems to work, especially for something that must be a one-time deal.

Input :

```
.ab_{background-image:url(../path/path/path/path/xxxxx.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;}
.ab_{background-image:url(../path/path/path/path/xxxxx1.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;}
.ab_{background-image:url(../path/path/path/path/xxxxx2.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;}
.ab_{background-image:url(../path/path/path/path/xxxxx3.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;}
```

Output :

```
.ab_xxxxx{background-image:url(../path/path/path/path/xxxxx.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;}
.ab_xxxxx1{background-image:url(../path/path/path/path/xxxxx1.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;}
.ab_xxxxx2{background-image:url(../path/path/path/path/xxxxx2.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;}
.ab_xxxxx3{background-image:url(../path/path/path/path/xxxxx3.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have to use Dreamweaver. It's not working for me.

Comment: Why would you __have to__ use Dreamweaver? Notepad++ can be installed and run from a thumb drive and is extremely light-weight.

Comment: Because for this site I'll be working exclusively on a Mac. Mac's can't run Notepad++.